# not finding jdk on my system windows 7?

Tags: windows, java

I am using eclipse for android app development. I didn't get any error or anything while creating android applications or simple core java programs.

I cannot find `jdk` on my system windows 7, only `jre6` is there.

I tried the below command but i didn't get any path :

```
C:> for %i in (javac.exe) do @echo.   %~$PATH:i
```

I have searched for `javac.exe` in my c drive but didn't find. There are only two folder in `C:\Program Files\Java`:  `jre1.6.0_18` and `jre6`

How can I find the path of jdk on my system ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's seems that you haven't installed the JDK but only the JRE. I suggest you to go to [Oracle Java Download Page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7u4-downloads-1591156.html) and install it.

Comment: is it possible to run the java and android applications successfully without jdk ??

Comment: sure jdk is the development env, for running apps you only need jre

Comment: Yes it is possible.  But it is not possible to *compile* programs without a compiler or an IDE.  The `javac` command is the compiler pf the standard Oracle/Java toolchain.

Comment: The reason you are not getting an error when building, and why you can't find javac, is that Eclipse has a compiler built-in (see http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/overview.php)

Answer (score 1):

Generally jdk is installed near to JRE (in most of the cases),  If you want to search for it You could do window search for `javac.exe`

Comment: i have searched but didn't get result for javac.exe

Comment: Then just go and setup new JDK